# Missing references Nuget library in the main project's output folder

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2022

Let's say I have three .NET 7.0 projects:

1. **Project A** (class library) with Nuget dependency
2. **Project B** (console app) with transient reference to **Project A**
3. **Main Project** (console app) which has transient reference to **Project A** and direct reference to **Project B**

All projects are part of one solution. When I build the solution, following happens:

- Project A doesn't copy any Nuget library to the bin folder.
- Project B copies the library referenced by Project A.
- Main Project doesn't copy the Nuget library.

Main Project not copying the library causes problems for me as it is needed for the Project B's executable to function properly (the executable with it's DLL assembly is present in the output folder). Spent almost three days to make it work without success.

I cannot figure out why the behavior varies so much. Any insight to the problem? Would appreciate it.

Tried

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

in the projects' properties. Worked for Project A but doesn't work with Main Project for some reason.

Comment: I'd be interested to see any answers for this. We had to add the NuGet packages to the leaf assemblies (Main project in your example) to fix this in some cases.

Comment: I've tried that too but for some reason the Nuget assembly doesn't get copied either, even when I try to force it. Probably MSBuild deems it unnecessary for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Does "transient reference" mean project reference(Add -> Project Reference), and "direct reference" mean reference the generated .dll file of Project B directly?

If so, it is strange. I tried to add a custom package reference(NuGet pacakge) to ProjectA and also tried to add a random NuGet package reference from nuget.org to ProjectA. The scenario one and two are the same, but Main Project did copy the NuGet library(.dll file). Is it reproducible on your side with newly created three projects?

I suggest first confirm that the "ProjectReference" is added to the MainProject.csproj file, like(in MainProject's .csproj file):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="XX\XXXX\ProjectA.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If above xml code lines weren't added, please add them between `<Project>` and `</Project>`. If there are some special or custom configurations in MainProject.csproj file, please double check and make sure that they will not block MainProject from referencing ProjectA, and they will not remove any files like NuGet libraries from output/destination folder.

In case any cache or VS settings affect and cause this issue, please try to rename the hidden .vs folder in your solution folder, remove bin and obj folders in your project folders. Consider reseting VS settings(run `devenv /ResetSettings` in `Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2022`) and repairing VS(VS Installer > More > Repair).

Since you mentioned "even try to force it, the NuGet assembly doesn't get copied", to double confirm this and as a temporarily workaround, please try to directly write a target in MainProject.csproj file and copy the NuGet library to the destination folder.

```
<Target Name="CopyFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
   <Copy
        SourceFiles="XX\XXXX\XXXX\XXX.dll"
        DestinationFolder="XX\XXXX\XXXX"
    />
</Target>
```

Besides, please go to Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build And Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity and set the option to Detailed then rebuild your project. Check the VS Output window after you rebuild the solution and let us know if you see any errors/warnings like failing to copy NuGet library/ignoring copying NuGet library/removing NuGet library...

Comment: Thank for your input. With "transient" reference I really meant "transitive", just picked the wrong word. Meaning referencing something indirectly.
Tried all you suggested but nothing helped. So in the end I'm just copying the DLL file using "Target" element from your last code snippet.

Comment: I still can't reproduce this issue, do I miss some steps? And may I know if this issue is reproducible on your side with three newly created projects?